# Get regular expression to parse data in xml format of a table column

Tags: sql, regex, xml, hive, impala

I have a table that contains a column with data in xml format. 
What I want to do is parsing some of the data in that column. 
The table looks like this:

```
SalesID | SalesDetail 
--------|------------------ 
403958  | <SalesCode>4</SalesCode><SalesMessage>Same day shipping to customer in TX<SalesMessage>
453324  | <SalesCode>4</SalesCode><SalesMessage>Customer complained issues at check-out <SalesMessage>
```

Could someone point directions to use Impala or Hive to parse out the data for SalesCode and SalesMessage?

I tried multiple regular expressions but it does not work out as the way I wanted. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected outcome that you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`xpath_string`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+XPathUDF#LanguageManualXPathUDF-xpath_string) and `xpath_int`:

```
SELECT xpath_int (SalesDetail, 'SalesCode') as SalesCode,
       xpath_string (SalesDetail, 'SalesMessage') as SalesMessage FROM src;
```

Comment: Thank you Alex for the re-formatting and solution tips!

Comment: @alibov I re-tried with your suggestion, and this is definitely helpful, but I am now running into another issue- the value returned for the SalesCode are all 0, while the SalesMessage returned empty string. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: What is the exact data you have? I just tested some queries and it seems that there needs to be an encapsulating element. In that case, it has to appear in the xpath: `elem/SalesCode`